# Convert angular1 javascript circular queue implementation for rolling average to typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am migrating project from angular1 to angular2.
I have one chart where it shows the moving average line. For this I need to use the circular queue where it is prototype having add, remove ,getAverage methods.

I have below code developed in angular 1 javascript and need to convert it to typescript.

Is there any way to import and call javascript functions from typescript 
or

Is there is way to convert javascript to typescript using any tool

Kindly help.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('testeApp.testChart')
    .service('testRollingAverageSrc', function(){
            this.performRollingAverage = RollingAverage;
            function RollingAverage() {
                if (!(this instanceof RollingAverage)) {
                    // multiple conditions need to be checked to properly emulate Array
                    if (arguments.length > 1 || typeof arguments[0] !== 'number') {
                        return RollingAverage.apply(new RollingAverage(arguments.length), arguments);
                    } else {
                        return new RollingAverage(arguments[0]);
                    }
                }
                // if no arguments, then nothing needs to be set
                if (arguments.length === 0)
                    throw new Error('Missing Argument: You must pass a valid buffer length');

                // this is the same in either scenario
                this.size = this.start = this.end = 0;
                this.overflow = null;
                this.totalSum =0.0;

                // emulate Array based on passed arguments
                if (arguments.length > 1 || typeof arguments[0] !== 'number') {
                    this.data = new Array(arguments.length);
                    this.end = (this.length = arguments.length) - 1;
                    this.push.apply(this, arguments);
                } else {
                    this.data = new Array(arguments[0]);
                    this.end = (this.length = arguments[0]) - 1;
                }
                return this;
            }
            RollingAverage.prototype = {
                remove : function () {
                    var item;
                    if (this.size === 0) return;
                    item = this.data[this.end];
                    // remove the reference to the object so it can be garbage collected
                    if( !isNaN(this.data[this.end]) )
                        this.totalSum -= this.data[this.end];
                    delete this.data[this.end];
                    this.end = ((this.end - 1 + this.length) % this.length);
                    this.size--;
                    return item;
                },
                add : function () {
                    var i = 0;
                    // check if overflow is set, and if data is about to be overwritten
                    if (this.overflow && this.size + arguments.length > this.length) {
                        // call overflow function and send data that's about to be overwritten
                        for (; i < this.size + arguments.length - this.length; i++) {
                            this.overflow(this.data[(this.end + i + 1) % this.length], this);
                        }
                    }
                    // push items to the end, wrapping and erasing existing items
                    // using arguments variable directly to reduce gc footprint
                    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                        // reduce the totalSum by the removed value
                        var value = this.data[(this.end + i + 1) % this.length];
                        if( !isNaN(value) )
                            this.totalSum -= value;
                        // save the new value
                        this.data[(this.end + i + 1) % this.length] = arguments[i];
                        // update totalSum
                        if( !isNaN((arguments[i])) )
                            this.totalSum += arguments[i];
                    }
                    // recalculate size
                    if (this.size < this.length) {
                        if (this.size + i > this.length) this.size = this.length;
                        else this.size += i;
                    }
                    // recalculate end
                    this.end = ((this.end + i) % this.length);
                    // recalculate start
                    this.start = (this.length + this.end - this.size + 1) % this.length;
                    return this.size;
                },
                avg : function () {
                    return this.size == 0 ? 0 : this.totalSum / this.size;
                }
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing about TypeScript is that it *is* JavaScript. Simply copy and paste that code over to a `.ts` file and it will work. It might be pertinent to refactor it into a more TypeScript way of doing things, such as changing it into a private method, but there is nothing stopping your code from working right out of the box.

Comment: I tried to put code as is in .ts file. also by tried to change to  @Injectable()
export class RollingAverageService but it doesnt work